# How to select a date from calendar using Selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h01Li.jpg)

Hello, I want to select 28th, but only use Xpath using two keywords together. I'll show you my code.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

start_date = '2022.1.28'
start_month = int(start_date.split('.')[1])
start_day = int(start_date.split('.')[2])

url = "http://naver.com"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"/Users/yuseonjong/Downloads/chromedriver")

driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window() 
element = driver.find_element_by_id("query")
element.send_keys("네이버 항공권") 
element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER) 

driver.find_element_by_class_name("link_name").click() 
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0]) 
driver.close() 
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0]) 

WebDriverWait(driver,timeout=10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "naver-splugin-dimmed")))

driver.find_elements_by_class_name("tabContent_option__2y4c6.select_Date__1aF7Y")[0].click()
########## here
day = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(f"//*[text()='{start_day}']")
monthday = day[start_month-1]
monthday.click()
```

I've made my code to collect all Xpath containing text '28'(the day I want to select), so all month's 28th are contained in list data like [Jan.28th, Feb.28th,...,Dec.28th].
I want to select January 28th, so use [0](like Jan-1) for indexing.

However, I want to find Xpath using two keys. One is text '2022.01'(month), the other is '27'(day). So, I wrote my code `driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//*[text()[contains(.,'2022.0{start_month}.')]]/text()[contains(.,'{start_day}')]")` but this is not working.

So, please tell me another ways.

Comment: Question heading is `How to select a date from calendar using Selenium in python` and you are asking multiple question inside it `However, I want to find Xpath using two keys. One is text '2022.01'(month), the other is '27'(day). So, I wrote my code driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//*[text()[contains(.,'2022.0{start_month}.')]]/text()[contains(.,'{start_day}')]") but this is not working.` what does it mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed to specify the tag type of the day and also to put // to ignore hierarchy
so I guess it should be
driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//*[text()[contains(.,'2022.0{start_month}.')]]//*[contains(.,'{start_day}')]")